# How to redirect_to or render new action with a HTTP GET method instead of POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error: No route matches [POST] "/posts/5/comments/new".

How do I redirect_to the GET action of my posts/comments/new route ( /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) ) instead of  the POST??

Here is my create action for the comments controller:

```
def create
   def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
      @comment.user_id = current_user.id #or whatever is you session name
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post
    else

      redirect_to new_post_comment_path
    end
      end
        end
```

If you look at the error message, you can see my create action is looking for a POST version of my new_post_comment_path route when it is supposed to be GET.

Some Output of rake routes:

```
POST    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  comments#create
new_post_comment_path   GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)  comments#new
```

How i did my routes:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
  end
  resources :comments
end
```

Comments _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: {action: "new"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "40x12" %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

When I change the action from new to create I get a new missing template error message:

Missing template comments/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>   [:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "app/views" * ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.3.0/app/views"

comment new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Comment</h1>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does your posts and comments models have relationship? please add your routes.rb file here

Comment: Are you defining a `create` method inside another `create` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a RESTful environment, you cannot use a POST verb to reach a "new" action on a controller. If you're confused with the routes, remember to use the command **rake routes** until you get used to them.

Regardless of this, I do not understand your question very well. If you want to redirect to the new action, it will always use GET, so it should be enough with:

```
redirect_to new_post_comment_path(@post)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I had that code before and it gets the same error.  I double checked. I will edit more info into the question.

Comment: Please note I missed the @ symbol in front of post, maybe is as simple as that.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the controller? How does your form look like? Maybe you can paste the log output as well

Comment: I just added it. I get a new error message posted in the edit when I change "new" to "create"

Comment: Just what I thought, your problem in on the form. You're sending the request to the action :new, with a POST method from the form, that doesn't make sense. Try this:
form_for [@post, @comment]
Remove the url section.